How to convert JSONL to parquet efficiently?
Given a jsonl file like this:
{"abc1": "hello world", "foo2": "foo bar"} 
{"foo2": "bar bar blah", "foo3": "blah foo"}

I could convert it to a dataframe like this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('mydata.jsonl') as fin:
    df = pd.json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(fin.read().splitlines())[0].apply(eval))


# Sometimes, there's some encoding issues, so this is done:
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == object:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x==np.nan else str(x).encode('utf8', 'replace').decode('utf8'))

df.to_parquet('mydata.parquet')

The above would work for small dataset but for dataset with billions of lines, reading everything into RAM is excessive and won't fit onto a normal machine.
Are there other ways to convert the dataset into parquet efficiently without reading the whole data into RAM?

There's no JSONL, that's just some guy's attempt to hijack the already common practice of storing unindented JSON objects as separate lines in text files, because appending to a file is the only operation that doesn't require reading and parsing the entire file. Other guys tried to push nd-json, json-nd and a bunch of other names. The common name is streaming json

You can use pd.read_json('mydata.jsonl',lines=True,chunksize=5000) to read from a streaming JSON file in chunks

Pandas 2.0 can already read JSON objects per line with pd.read_json(file,lines=True). The read_json docs show you can read streaming JSON with the lines=True argument
The entire script could be as short as :
df=pd.read_json('mydata.jsonl',lines=True,engine='pyarrow')
df.to_parquet('mydata.parquet')

You can use the chunksize parameter to load the data in chunks and process one chunk at a time :
with pd.read_json('mydata.jsonl',lines=True, chunksize=10000) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        print(chunk)

You can append to an existing parquet file by using the fastparquet engine with the append=True parameter:
source=Path(r"mydata.jsonl")
target=Path("mydata.parquet")

with pd.read_json(source,lines=True,chunksize=10000) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        if not target.exists():
            chunk.to_parquet(target, engine='fastparquet')            
        else:
            chunk.to_parquet(target,
                             engine='fastparquet', 
                             append=True)            

This could fail if a chunk has different columns from the existing file though.

Building on this method to write parquet in chunks, you could do this:
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from tqdm import tqdm


# convert from jsonl to a generator of DataFrames
def jsonl_to_chunked_dfs(file_name, chunk_size):
    with open(file_name, encoding="utf8") as f:
        current_chunk = []
        next_line = next(f, None)
        while next_line is not None:
            if len(current_chunk) < chunk_size:
                current_chunk.append(next_line)
                next_line = next(f, None)
            else:
                yield pd.json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(current_chunk)[0].apply(eval))
                current_chunk = []
        yield pd.json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(current_chunk)[0].apply(eval))


# use stream of DataFrames to write each of them to parquet
def write_chunked_dfs_to_parquet(dfs, file_name):
    for i, chunk in tqdm(enumerate(dfs)):
        if i == 0:
            parquet_schema = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=chunk).schema
            parquet_writer = pq.ParquetWriter(file_name, parquet_schema, compression='snappy')
        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=parquet_schema)
        parquet_writer.write_table(table)
    parquet_writer.close()


jsonl_file = 'mydata.jsonl'
parquet_file = 'mydata.parquet'
chunksize = 10_000

chunked_dfs = jsonl_to_chunked_dfs(jsonl_file, chunk_size=chunksize)
write_chunked_dfs_to_parquet(chunked_dfs, parquet_file)

You might have to re-add your encoding fix and you could experiment with methods of converting each list of dictionaries to a DataFrame to speed this up some more.

pyarrow has got support for jsonl
import pyarrow.json
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pyarrow.json.read_json("data.jsonl")
pq.write_table(table, "data.parquet")


But it can only read one file.
You could try to split the file in chunks, and write each chunk using a ParquetFileWriter here's a rudimental way to do it, but I think there are better ways.

import pyarrow as pa

with pq.ParquetWriter(
    "data.parquet",
    schema=pa.schema(
        [
            pa.field("abc1", pa.string()),
            pa.field("foo2", pa.string()),
        ]
    ),
) as writer:
    with open("data.jsonl", "rb") as fp:
        while True:
            tmp_lines = fp.readlines(1)
            if tmp_lines:
                break
            with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
                for line in tmp_lines:
                    print("FOO", line)
                    buffer.write(line)
                buffer.seek(0)
                table = pyarrow.json.read_json(buffer)
                writer.write(table)


